# dump Mysql to MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, миграция

Имеется .sql с дампом данных из mysql, необходимо перенести структуру в mssql.
Использовать SSMA не могу т.к. подключения к mysql нет.
Как вариант можно руками переписать все запросы, но что-то мне подсказывает, что имеются готовые инструменты для миграции.
Подскажите варианты реализации переноса .sql файла из mysql в mssql? 
Спасибо.

Comment: А если развернуть mysql , залить в нее дамп и уже из нее сделать выгрузку стандартным `mysqldump --compatible=mssql`

Comment: можно и так, но хотел обойтись без этого

Comment: Ну совсем просто конвертнуть наверное не выйдет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621682/import-mysql-database-into-a-ms-sql-server

Comment: читал эту ветку, но надеялся, что есть решение